# Is 3-4 player endgame necessarily a deadlock?

Tags: labyrinth

I played Ravensburger's *Labyrinth* with two friends, and we didn't manage to finish the game.

As far as I can see, you can never effectively move your piece more than 2 steps during your turn (step 1 by shifting the space you're standing on, step 2 by making your step). With 3+ players, you also can't limit what shifts your opponents make in any way (with 2 players, you could shift a row in one direction and then your opponent can't shift that row in the opposite direction that turn; with 3 players, player A shifts a row, player B can't reverse it, player C can).

Assuming all players always prefer to prevent an opponent from winning the game next move, **how is it possible to finish the game?** I assume that if you wait until 2 players are positioned close to their goals, then eventually a situation might occur where the deadlock would be broken... but that's a rather tiresome conclusion.

Comment: My English version is called "The aMAZEing Labyrinth", did the German version just go by "Labyrinth"? Also, my rules indicate that you can move as far as you want on your turn, not just a single space. Your explanation seems to indicate only moving a single square dungeon tile (in addition to the shift).

Comment: @user1873: Oh, holy expletive! Yeah, the "aMAZEing" pun is part of the name in some editions, and **yes**, I've been misreading the rules completely. Well, I sure feel sheepish... Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps the question could be reworded (using the proper rules), to ask if it is possible for two players to lock out an opponent, making it impossible for them to reach the exit. I don't think it is, but that doesn't mean some one couldn't prove this with analysis.

Comment: Don't change the question please. The fact that you asked the question indicates that there has been a realistic (happened in real life) confusion. It is not impossible that any other player ends up having the same confusion and searches for answers on this site, and then this question will provide the answer. If you change the question, perhaps you make a question that is never searched for because it is not realistic.

Comment: Seems like an OK question.  Misreading rules is pretty common.  I think most folks around here have been guilty of it on a couple occasions:)  Welcome to B&CG!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this translation of the rules](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/8pn5wt94z/a_Maze_ing_Labyrinth_Rules.pdf?), **you can move your piece as far as you like down an open corridor**, not just one step.